# Dynamodb scan from AWS Lambda takes a lot longer than from local machine

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have a relatively small DynamoDB table (about 1000+ records of maybe few hundred bytes each or smaller). When I use boto3 to scan the Dynamodb table from my machine, it returns the 1000+ records instantaneously. However when I perform the exact same operation in an AWS Python Lambda, it takes upward of 15 seconds to return the same quantum of data.

I have read about the 1MB limit and that doesn't seem to explain it, we are not returning that much data. I tried increasing the read capacity of the table to 3 units. But it does not seem to have made a difference.

Any insights would be appreciated.

I did try to turn up debugging
Thanks, good suggestion. At log level DEBUG there is

```
2020-07-10T14:52:18.302Z Calling dynamodb:scan with {'TableName': 'SIUser'}

2020-07-10 14:52:28,973 boto3.resources.action [DEBUG] Response: [entire response here].
```

Which leads me to believe it fetched all the data in one shot. The bulk of the time is the 10 seconds this part took.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you turn on debugging mode in boto3 and post the logs?

Comment: Increase the RAM size for your Lambda function e.g. to 1GB. Does it make a difference?

Comment: @Shawn - yes i did set the logging level to DEBUG. But jarmod you may be on to something. I did just create a standalone test driver (lambda) and tried to increase memory to 1 GB and the duration dropped right away!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since boto3 DynamoDB scan is network IO based task, it is important to have enough compute resources if you want to complete the operation in timely fashion.

Function gets CPU power proportional to its memory allocation. Try increasing memory limit in increments of, say, 256 Mb and look whether it helps.

Comment: Here is a good blog on the subject to accompany the answer
https://engineering.opsgenie.com/how-does-proportional-cpu-allocation-work-with-aws-lambda-41cd44da3cac